# vscode isn't making any sound after Console.Beep()

Tags: c#, visual-studio-code, audio, terminal

This is the most simple program I can make right now. I'm just learning C# and basically vscode isn't making any sound after using Console.Beep(). A friend of mine did the same code and it is working for him, any help? (Tried using both vscode terminal and code runner).

```
using System;

namespace Progetto
{
    internal class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("What's your name? ");
            String name = Console.ReadLine();

            Console.WriteLine("Hi, " + name + ". How old are you?");
            int age = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

            Console.Write("So your name is " + name + " and you're " + age + " years old.");

            Console.Beep();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: vscode is not something that bleeps. Blame your BIOS speaker for that :)

Comment: Open a CMD window. Navigate to your project's target folder and run the EXE that your code compiled into. Does it beep?

Comment: @Flydog57 I tried and still no beep sound D:

Also onlinegdb makes the sound if that makes some difference even if it is a website.

Comment: That means (as @eldar pointed put), that your PC has no beep. The beep is performed at a very low level in your computer (at the level of the BIOS). The spec for the beep is 40 years old. It might be that modern PCs just skip it

Comment: @Flydog57 my pc is pretty modern so that might be the problems, thanks both of you.

Comment: I use a "HP EliteDesk 800 G4 DM 35W" mini desktop computer. This computer outputs the beep using the sound card. Have a look at this video and see if you can also see the same visual indication about the 'BEEP' sound as I do.
https://www.screencast.com/t/TvGZGyVqO